# Bake Linux Kernel modules with dependencies with Openembedded

Tags: cross-compiling, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

The Linux Kernel Modules (LKM) B depends on Symbols provided by LKM A.

Thus the following is required to build LKM B:

- Header files from LKM A
- Symbol-table (see [Kbuild
  Documentation for details](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt#L484))

I use a BitBake recipe to build LKMs A and B. What I do:

- I propagate the header files and the symbol-table of LKM A into the staging include directory `${STAGING_INCDIR}`.
- I feed the staging include and the
  path to the symbol-table as
  `KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS`variable into
  the Makefile of LKM B

Example:

```
#BB-recipe  for LKM A 
# Staging of .h files and symbol-table 
do_install_append () {
  install -d ${STAGING_INCDIR} 
  install ${WORKDIR}/${PN}/src/*.h ${STAGING_INCDIR}/ 
  install ${WORKDIR}/${PN}/Module.symvers ${STAGING_INCDIR}/rtserial.symvers
} 

#BB-recipe for LKM B
do_compile () {
unset CFLAGS CPPFLAGS CXXFLAGS LDFLAGS CC LD CPP
cd "${WORKDIR}/mstp"
oe_runmake KDIR="${KERNEL_SOURCE}" \
         ARCH="${ARCH}" \
         CROSS_COMPILE="${CROSS_COMPILE}" \
         IDIR="${STAGING_INCDIR}" \
         KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS="${STAGING_INCDIR}/rtserial.symvers" \
         build
 }
```

**Questions:**

- Is the do_install_append the right task to stage shared resources? I read that do_staging() is [somewhat deprecated](http://www.openembedded.org/index.php/Legacy_staging) ...
- Where to stage the symbol-table?

Thanks for any Best Practices hints.

Comment: Would like to bring in the [openembedded] tag... but I'm not rich enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With current OpenEmbedded and non "legacy" staging, no staging is done directly anymore.  Everything gets installed to standard locations with do_install (that is, relative to ${D} rather than the staging locations), and the system automatically populates the sysroot(s) based upon that.  So, I'd suggest installing KVM A's headers to ${D}${includedir}/${PN}, and install the symbol table to ${D}${datadir}/${PN}, then KVM B still looks at STAGING_INCDIR and STAGING_DATADIR to get at those files.  You may need to set NATIVE_INSTALL_WORKS = "1" to let it know that the modified do_install is safe to use with new style staging.